# How to create a pointcloud from array in open3d-cpp

Tags: c++, memory, eigen, point-clouds, open3d

I am using [**open3d-cpp**](http://www.open3d.org/html/cpp_api/index.html) to process some pointclouds. However, the raw input is a float array (say `float pts[3000]`, containing 1000 points), and I didn't find an efficient way to transform it into an `open3d::geometry::Pointcloud`, as the only [parameterized constructor of `Pointcloud`](http://www.open3d.org/html/cpp_api/classopen3d_1_1geometry_1_1_point_cloud.html) is a copy constructor and only takes `std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>` as input.

I made a naive converter, but I think it is not quite efficient, the first step is converting the float array (`arr` of size `40000*3`) into a double array, then do the following:

```
    long t01 = CurrTimeMS;
    Eigen::Vector3d *vv = reinterpret_cast<Eigen::Vector3d *>(arr);
    vector<Eigen::Vector3d> vec(vv, vv+40000);
    geometry::PointCloud pcd(vec);
    long t02 = CurrTimeMS;
    std::cout << "pcd init took " << t02-t01 << " ms.\n";
    cout << (void *) vv << " " << (void *) vec.data() << " " << (void *) pcd.points_.data() << endl;
```

It turned out taking me 3-4ms, and because `std::vector(T *start, T *end)` is also a copy constructor, this code does 3 times of memory copy (all three addressed are different), which is not optimal.
Is there any more efficient way to create Pointcloud directly from memory?

Comment: It looks like the `points_` member of `geometry::PointCloud` is public, so you could create an empty pointcloud and directly copy your values into it (you can also do the conversion on-the-fly).

Comment: nice, I finally create a `PointCloud` first and use `vector::assign` to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

I end up finding a relatively efficient approach.

```
std::shared_ptr<open3d::geometry::PointCloud> convert2pcd(float *data, size_t N, size_t dim=3) {
    assert(dim > 2);
    double *dd = new double[N*3];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            dd[i*3+j] = (double) data[i*dim+j];
        }
    }
    Eigen::Vector3d *vv = reinterpret_cast<Eigen::Vector3d *>(dd);
    auto pcd = std::make_shared<open3d::geometry::PointCloud>();
    pcd->points_.assign(vv, vv+N);
    delete[] dd;
    return pcd;
}
```

which still takes me around 2-3ms.